# Import of applications fails with unclear message on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

From the /import web page, accessed through "Add an application" link in the "Edit profile" page, my projects can not be imported and the error message is not clear:

1. Go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/project/65831
2. Type https://www.civiclinks.it/en/
3. Click "Get project"
4. The "Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason." error message appears.

The same behaviour appears using these links:

- http://www.civiclinks.it/en/
- http://www.civiclinks.it
- http://factchecking.civiclinks.it/

Comment: Might the HEAD request be failing (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132026/careers-2-0-cannot-retrieve-url-of-blog-post-i-wrote)?

Comment: Using http://web-sniffer.net/ it appears to reply with a 200 (on HTTPS). HTTP replies with a 301/Moved permanently, but it seems correct.

Comment: These URLs redirect to `https://` equivalents, perhaps you should try the 302 endpoint instead? If that does work (e.g.`https://www.civiclinks.it/en/`) then Careers 2.0 should be updated to follow 30x redirects properly. If that doesn't work, perhaps Careers 2.0 doesn't handle (some?) SSL sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters All the above mentioned endpoints have been tried and noone works (i.e. HTTP and HTTPS, returning redirect and OK answers).

Comment: Well, since your SSL cert is a DigiCert issue, it looks like Careers 2.0 either cannot handle HTTPS sites at all, or doesn't handle `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`; I don't see anything wrong with your sites in any case.

Comment: Happened to me with importing articles a while back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125403/cant-add-an-article-on-my-careers-profile. They managed to fix it at the time though. Could it be the same issue here?

Comment: @Tudor behavior seems compatible with the one of your issue: it gets a while for the error message to appear. however, HTTPS returns a 200, not a redirect, so I don't know what happens under the hood on the careers website.

Comment: @Sid: I went ahead and put a bounty to get things moving. Hopefully a mod/staff will see it now and attempt a fix.

Comment: @Tudor: Hey, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works now, and probably has for some time. Likely related to the HEAD issue listed in the comments (we switched back to a GET).