# Reminder of bounty expiration on someone else's question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, email, wording

I put a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144303/import-of-applications-fails-with-unclear-message-on-careers) but unfortunately there are no answers yet. Today I received a reminder by email that my bounty is about to expire. The part of the text that seems weird is (emphasis by me):

> Thanks for putting a bounty on **your question**. It looks like there are
>   still no answers yet. You should consider **improving your question** to
>   attract more answers. Could you:
>
> add more text describing the problem? 
>   add or change the tags? 
>   update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?

However, this is not my question, but Sid's question.

Should there be a different text in the email if I put a bounty on someone else's question? 
Or also have an email sent to the original author telling them that "a bounty by someone else is about to expire could you please improve your question"? 
Because as it stands, the text in the email does not really match the "situation".

Comment: Well, the email is still wrong, but you can improve someone else's question if you want to.  That's part of the beauty of SO.

Comment: @Servy: I agree, but I'm usually against changing a question substantially without the approval of contribution of the OP, so you'd still have to involve them.

Comment: I got a similar email today regarding a bounty I placed on someone else's question. I only had one bounty running though so I knew what it was referring to :)

Comment: It looks like this is fixed now, see [Bounty expiration email is wrong for bounties on others' questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323586)

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in 2016 see [Bounty expiration email is wrong for bounties on others' questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323586/bounty-expiration-email-is-wrong-for-bounties-on-others-questions) on Meta Stack Overflow.

After the fix, when the bounty was placed on someone else question, this is the email text:

> Thanks for putting a bounty on a question. It looks like there are still no answers yet. If appropriate, you might consider improving the question to attract more answers.

Comment: you didn't get this email because looks like there were always answers posted after you started the bounty.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda: there were always answer's posted at the time when the bounty was going to expire.